# Problems understanding error building Java Shim Client JAR

Tags: java, windows, gradle

When building the Java shim client JAR I have come across following error message. However, I am new at this and don't quite understand the message. Anyone could help to explain, and guide to further reading to resolve this? Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

What went wrong:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':core:chaincode:shim:java'.
>   No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs.source
>   () is applicable for argument types: (com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufSourceD
>   irectorySet_Decorated) values: [main Proto source]
>
> Possible solutions: collect(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)`

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading gradle to 2.14 solved my problem.